# winscard.dll warm up

Tags: c#, dll, smartcard

first of all I want to specified that formaly i'm a java programmer, but now i have to move for a while to C# programming in visual studio 2010 express for building a piece of program which read and write to smardcard (sle4428). And I have a couple of question.

1) I've seen some documentation about the winscard.dll api in [this url](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379773.aspx), but in the signature of the function there aren't the data type of parameter but only in or out. (Doh) Exists a way to unterstand which type I have to use?

2)Exists some code example of how initialize a communication, without searching in "google search code"

3) The custumer provided to me basic VB code, can I build something which I can use in a C# context?

Thnaks guys for any help!!!!

Comment: Right communication with a smartcard reader scr3310

Answer (score 5):

Hope this helps:
http://pastie.org/1527598

Answer (score 0):

The URL you've provided actually does show the types. `LONG WINAPI SCardGetStatusChange(   __in     SCARDCONTEXT hContext, ...` means that the first argument is formally named `hContext`, and has type `SCARDCONTEXT`.

The same page links to [another page with an example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa379794%28VS.85%29.aspx).

Whether the VB code is useful at all depends on whether it's VB.Net. That would show the correct P/invoke forms.

Comment: So in the end there is not a direct way to map the formal parameter with their own type. many many thanks

Comment: "Direct way to map", "their own type" ? Why do you need to "map" anything? The page you linked to contained every argument type of every argument.